# Is the Arduino Due compatible with a Dual VNH5019 Motor Driver Shield?

Tags: arduino-due, arduino-motor-shield

I'm planning on buying an Arduino Due and there is a shield I would like to attach to it. I have seen a lot of things saying that some shields are **not** compatible with Arduino Due... I was wondering if the Arduino Due is compatible with the Dual VNH5019 Motor Driver Shield.

This is where I'm buying it from if you need any extra information on the items:

- [The Arduino Due](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A6C3JN2)
- [The Dual VNH5019 Motor Driver Shield](https://www.pololu.com/product/2507)

Answers greatly appreciated! If you need any specifications let me know.

Comment: It is probably electrically compatible if wired point to point, though unclear if direct stacking as a shield would work.  The provided library is AVR-only, though it shouldn't be that difficult to write something that would work on a different processor.  The pins best suited for PWM may be in a different places, which could mean a choice between inefficient software or rewiring.

Comment: so its compatible, but the pins must be connected to the correct points?
so I cant just slap the shield on top?

Comment: That is unclear.  What was posted was a comment examining potential issues, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I went ahead and bought the arduino due and officially tested it out and the Arduino Due **is** compatible with the Dual VNH5019 Motor Driver Shield!

hope this helps!